# Crash happend when startup an activity from FlutterView

Tags: android, flutter

I just start an activity from a flutterview, then crash happend. Infomations about it.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.View.getContext()' on a null object reference
            at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.checkInputConnectionProxy(PlatformViewsController.java:336)
            at io.flutter.view.FlutterView.checkInputConnectionProxy(FlutterView.java:402)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1354)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onAmigoPostWindowFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1845)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6354)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1111)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:972)
```

Comment: Wrap your code in tripple backticks (`) for better readability, please ;)

Comment: that`s different